# Why was Simon so quick to blame people for Maddie's death?

Tags: school-spirits

Over the course of the first season of *School Spirits*, Simon accuses a good six people of having killed Maddie, including her mother and her boyfriend's new girlfriend, usually dragging a skeptical Maddie along. This is particularly notable because his initial suspicions are often based on rather thin evidence—notably, his initial suspicion of Nicole appears to be based on "she took too many pictures of Maddie"—and because he usually insisted on them against the skepticism of the ghost of the actual murder victim.

In conjunction with the fact that he is the only person who can see Maddie, this would make perfect sense had he been the murderer, since he would naturally want to deflect suspicion from himself.

However, with the end of the final episode seemingly indicating that

> Janet forced Maddie out of her body, that Maddie's body is likely not even dead, and that Maddie could somehow see and hear two ghosts before her "death,"

this explanation seems rather unlikely.

Why was Simon so insistent on accusing people of murdering Maddie?

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer because I have never seen the show. But I have lost both of my parents and through that have noticed that my brother and I grieve differently. Some people need to find somebody to blame when someone close to them passes. So they will look at anyone and everyone as possible causes.